# Assigning hexadecimal value to char variable

Tags: c, hex

I want to store a hex value with leading zeros into a char pointer. 
What I did before, to test my program, was this:

```
printf("%06x : ", offset);
```

So when I had an offset of e.g. 16, the output was 000010. 32 was 000020.
My goal is to store that value into a variable or assign it to a pointer. In the end, I want to connect all the different strings via `strcat()`.

Is there any way to get there??
Thank you so much!

Comment: see [`s(n)printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) functions

Comment: this is what i was looking for! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`sprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
char buffer[7];
sprintf(buffer, "%06x : ", offset);
```

Comment: I used char *temp instead and got an sementation fault. I think it was because I did not restrict the number of bytes to read. Can I simply go like this: 
char *temp = NULL;
snprintf(temp,  [how can I determine the size of output formated to hex?]   ,"%06x : ", offset);

Comment: No, you cannot write to a pointer that points to `NULL`. Maybe read #3 of the [Ten Commandments for C Programmers](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html).